In Polars >=v1, what is the correct way to check if a datatype meets a selector criteria?
Prior to v1, this was the prefered way to check if a Polars datatype (e.g., looked up from a schema dict) is numeric:
import polars as pl

assert pl.UInt8 in pl.selectors.NUMERIC_DTYPES
assert pl.UInt8 not in pl.selectors.TEMPORAL_DTYPES

However, as of >=v1, it seems that these type lists aren't exported. Pyright gives the following error, for example:
"TEMPORAL_DTYPES" is not exported from module "polars.selectors" (Pylance reportPrivateImportUsage)

I'm aware that the selector API exists, but I'm still unable to figure out a basic type comparison like that.
I'm expecting something like this:
assert pl.selectors.numeric().contains(pl.UInt8)


pl.NUMERIC_DTYPES exists but is deprecated (prints a DeprecationWarning).

pl.UInt8 in pl.datatypes.group.NUMERIC_DTYPES  works without deprecation warning but not sure if it's meant to be public. (https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/blob/py-1.9.0/py-polars/polars/datatypes/group.py)

Use the .is_*() methods available for all datatypes (docs):
import polars as pl

assert pl.UInt8.is_numeric()
assert not pl.UInt8.is_temporal()


These frozenset constants can be loaded from polars.datatypes.group now.
For example:
from polars.datatypes.group import NUMERIC_DTYPES, TEMPORAL_DTYPES

assert pl.UInt8 in NUMERIC_DTYPES
assert pl.UInt8 not in TEMPORAL_DTYPES

